# woocommerce cart product names into dropdown

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to create a snippet at the checkout of woocommerce to take a dropdown list with the label course1 and add all product titles as selections.

as im new to php in general, im struggling to figure out how I would pull the names of the products in the cart.

any tips would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get cart items from global $woocommerce object

```
global $woocommerce;
$items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
echo "<select name='products-list'">;
foreach($items as $item => $values) { 
    $_product = $values['data']->post; 
    $price = get_post_meta($values['product_id'] , '_price', true);
    echo "<option value=".$values['product_id'].">".$_product->post_title."-".$price."</option>";   
        } 
echo "</select>";
```

Use this PHP snippet where you want to show dropdown list

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but where/how do you feed that into a preexisting dropdown called course1 on the page? I'm trying to add it as a snippet to my functions.php

Comment: Either you should append these options (product names) to existing dropdown or name this generated newly dropdown as course1.  Use hooks like woocommerce_after_cart_table to display your dropdown from functions.php.  You can refer WordPress codex or woocommerce documentation about using hooks.